# Build polymer project as a reusable component

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to build a reusable web component with polymer 2.
Is there a way to do the bundling with polymer-build in such a way that in my application I would be able to import only the component via `<link import>` and the JavaScript poly-fill without modifications?
Currently all the bundling options generate a very complicated HTML from the "entrypoint" which is actually a test page and not the actual component.